# Sharing data between MainActivity and SurfaceView

Tags: java, android

I am very new to android studio and I'm not that comfortable with Java.

My question is, how can I use a function that I made in my MainActivity into a SurfaceView ?

I'll explain my situtation better : user takes a picture. Then it's saved (my function onPictureTaken). But the user must enter the name of the image so that it is registered with its identifier and not currentTimeMillis.

In the MainActivity, I retrieve what is entered in the EditText but I don't know how to communicate the two things.

**How I get the text :**

```
public void getText()
    {
        EditText text = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.imageName);
        String nomPhoto = text.getText().toString();
        if (nomPhoto.trim().equals("")) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Enter the name of the file", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;
        }
    }
```

**How I save the pic :**

```
 @Override
        public void onPictureTaken(byte[] arg0, Camera arg1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            photo = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(arg0, 0, arg0.length);

            //Save pic
            if(photo!=null)
            {

                File file=new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/dir");

                if(!file.isDirectory())
                {
                    file.mkdir();
                }

                //User must enter the pic name

                file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/dir",System.currentTimeMillis()+".jpg");

                try
                {

                    FileOutputStream fileOutputStream=new FileOutputStream(file);
                    photo.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG,100,fileOutputStream);
                    fileOutputStream.flush();
                    System.out.println(file);
                    fileOutputStream.close();


                }

                catch(IOException e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                catch(Exception exception)
                {
                    exception.printStackTrace();
                }


            }

            System.out.println("Pic taken");
            monTimer mt=new monTimer();
            maCamera.release();
            maCamera=null;
            mt.start();

        }
```

I tried this, but I had a Java PointerNullException

```
@Override
public void onPictureTaken(byte[] arg0, Camera arg1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    photo = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(arg0, 0, arg0.length);

    //Enregistrer photo sur téléphone
    if(photo!=null)
    {

        File file=new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/dir");

        if(!file.isDirectory())
        {
            file.mkdir();
        }

        MainActivity obj = new MainActivity();
        String tv = obj.storePhotoName();

        file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/dir",tv+".jpg");
```

Maybe it has somethings to do with an handler, but I really don't know

Thanks !

Comment: Don't post code images, post the code. Add the full stack trace of the exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I just found the answer :

```
//I get the associate xml file
LinearLayout r = (LinearLayout)this.getParent();
//get the EditText
imageName = r.findViewById(R.id.imageName);
```

Then, we need to check if the field is empty or not. If not, we can save the file :

```
if (imageName.getText().toString()!=""){
file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/dir",imageName.getText()+".jpg")};
```

Answer (score 2):

You can send data from one activity to another through `Intent`

```
Intent nextActivity = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), nextActivityName.class);
nextActivity.putExtra("key", "data");
startActivity(nextActivity);
```

Now in next activity, you can get this data

```
Intent i = getIntent();
String str = i.getStringExtra("key");
```

make sure that you use the same `key` value in `getStringExtra` method that you used to pass the data in `putExtra` method.

Comment: Oh yes, intent are very useful, thanks !

But my problem is not about that, I'm stupid I didn't realize I need to use intent with context right ?

Because I am using a SurfaceView (my function onPictureTaken is in that file).

It's sharing data between an activity (MainActivity) and a "view"

Comment: If i understand your problem correctly, you want to call a method in `MainActivity` from another Activity ?

Comment: I want to call a method from MainActivity in SurfaceView

Comment: You can make that method `static` or why not have that method inside `MainActivity` ?

Comment: Because it was our exercise to make separate files. But I just found the answer, I'll post it in a minute :)

But thanks for help, it helped me to understand some things